# Authentication in geoserver with openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

Is there a way to authenticate in geoserver with a external webpage (made with asp.net and openlayers)? I have restricted the access data only by certain users, and I don't want to authenticate this way:

```
username:password@geoserverurl
```

for security reasons (the username and password are visible in the webpage code)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Few days ago i post this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13123640/1202001 for the same question